# How to parse list in android?

Tags: java, android, model, adaptor

List have below declaration

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

Sample data:-

```
[{Minutes=25, Catagory=Morning, Hour=11, medName=hdodu, ImgPath=/storage/emulated/0/H/hdodu.jpg},
 {Minutes=25, Catagory=Night, Hour=3, medName=hdodu, ImgPath=/storage/emulated/0/H/hdodu.jpg}, 
 {Minutes=33, Catagory=Afternoon, Hour=16, medName=jsindj, ImgPath=/storage/emulated/0/H/jsindj.jpg}]
```

How do I print data of list using model class

**Model.java**

```
public class ListMedicine  {

private String Medicine_name;
private String Reminder_hour;
private String Reminder_min;
private String Reminder_catagory;
private String Medicine_image_path;


public void setMedicine_name(String medicine_name)
{
 this.Medicine_name=medicine_name;
}

public String getMedicine_name()
{
    return Medicine_name;
}

public void setReminder_hour(String reminder_hour)
{
    this.Reminder_hour=reminder_hour;
}

public String getReminder_hour()
{
    return Reminder_hour;
}

public void setReminder_min(String reminder_min)
{
    this.Reminder_min=reminder_min;
}

public String getReminder_min()
{
    return Reminder_min;
}

public void setReminder_catagory(String reminder_catagory)
{
    this.Reminder_catagory=reminder_catagory;
}

public String getReminder_catagory()
{
    return Reminder_catagory;
}

public void setMedicine_image_path(String medicine_image_path)
{
    this.Medicine_image_path=medicine_image_path;
}

public String getMedicine_image_path()
{
    return Medicine_image_path;
}

}
```

MedicineAdaptor.java

Below is the code for adaptor class in which I am using recyclerView to list down the data.

```
public class MedicineAdaptor extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MedicineAdaptor.ViewHolder> {

    List<ListMedicine> items;
    DbHelper dbHelper;
    Context context;

    public MedicineAdaptor(Context context, List<ListMedicine> items)
    {
        super();
        dbHelper=new DbHelper(context);
        Log.i("In the MedicineAdaptor","Constructor");
        this.context=context;
        this.items=items;

    }



    @Override
    public MedicineAdaptor.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        Log.i("Entering","onCreateViewHolder");

        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.medicine,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MedicineAdaptor.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Log.i("Entering","onBindViewHolder");

        ListMedicine listMedicine=items.get(position);

        Log.i("Medicine Name", listMedicine.getMedicine_name());
        Log.i("Medicine Hour", listMedicine.getReminder_hour());
        Log.i("Medicine Min",listMedicine.getReminder_min());
        Log.i("Medicine Catagory", listMedicine.getReminder_catagory());

        holder.MedicineName.setText(listMedicine.getMedicine_name());
        holder.ReminderHour.setText(listMedicine.getReminder_hour());
        holder.ReminderMin.setText(listMedicine.getReminder_min());
        holder.ReminderCatagory.setText(listMedicine.getReminder_catagory());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.i("Size is", Integer.toString(items.size()));
        return items.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView MedicineName, ReminderHour,ReminderMin, ReminderCatagory;
        public ImageView MedicineThumbnail;


        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            MedicineName=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.medicine_name);
            ReminderHour=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reminder_hour);
            ReminderMin=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.reminder_hour);
            ReminderCatagory=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.medicine_catagory);
            MedicineThumbnail=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.medicine_icon);
        }
    }
}
```

Database Fetch Code:

```
public ArrayList<ListMedicine> fetchReminder(String date)
    {

        ArrayList<ListMedicine> array_list=new ArrayList<ListMedicine>();

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from reminders",null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        try {

            while(c.isAfterLast() == false){
                Log.i("Inside the fetch query","yes");

                ListMedicine listMedicine=new ListMedicine();

                listMedicine.setMedicine_name(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("medName")));

                array_list.add(listMedicine);

                c.moveToNext();
            }



        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return array_list;
    }
```

Code of the calling Activity

```
private void showData() {
        ArrayList<ListMedicine> list=new ArrayList<ListMedicine>();

        Log.i("Show Data function","Yes");


        try {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);

            Log.i("Length is ",Integer.toString(arr.length()));

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length(); i++){

                ListMedicine bean = new ListMedicine();

                bean.setMedicine_name(bean.getMedicine_name());



                // at last add this into your list
                Log.i("Bean ans", bean.toString());
                list.add(bean);

            }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        adapter=new MedicineAdaptor(this,list);
        reminderList.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    private void getData(String fetchDate) {

        //ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();

        result=db.fetchReminder(fetchDate);

        Log.i("Result",result.toString());


    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android), although quite frankly it could be about anything...

Comment: You can refer this answer for your question [List example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39659915/6798867)

Comment: From your question it looks like you've already figured out how to print the data...

Comment: I think your sample data is incorrect format JSON.

Comment: Sample Data is  correct but i need to change my model class. That I don't know what need to change. @RoShanShan

Comment: Use this link to check format json. [link] https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your 
 `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

into

```
ArrayList<ListMedicine> result=new ArrayList<ListMedicine>();
```

Do it like this

```
try {
     JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
     for(int i=0;i<arr.length(); i++){
        JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        ListMedicine bean = new ListMedicine();
        bean.setMedicine_name(obj.getString("medName"));
        .
        .
        .
       // at last add this into your list
       result.add(bean);
     }


}catch (Exception e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Result arraylist is hashmap type not String type.. I need to change my model class but don't know what need to change

Comment: so you want key and value into hashMap list ?

Comment: I want to parse given data into single array list so that using model class I can list each row in recycle view

Comment: so why you need an single array list you can directly parse it. Array List is used for multiple object not for a single object

Comment: So how would I parse it.

Comment: I can't change the type of list as the data I am fetching from the sqllite database.

Comment: how are you fetching it from database? show me the code

Comment: Check Updated Code.  I try to fetch data from database using Model Class

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal where is the issue now ? why are you creating Array list of HashMap<String,String>?

Comment: I don't know as I am hesitating in using model class. but now in the adapter class size is equal to zero..

Comment: result=db.fetchReminder(fetchDate);

 Log.i("Result",result.toString());      Output :-[Model.ListMedicine@250c8ab0, Model.ListMedicine@cb8dd29, Model.ListMedicine@34ced8ae]

Comment: Nops in the adaptor class at getItemCount() is returning size zero

Comment: change your List into ArrayList for adapter

Comment: I think bean.setMedicine_name(obj.getString("medName")); should be  change.

Comment: its fine, check your logcat if you are getting any error

Comment: JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);   arr.length() is returning 3 .  org.json.JSONException: Value at 0 is null.

Comment: then your json response is not correct. make it correct and check it at www.jsonlint.com

Comment: Which response is wrong? Data fetching from database? I showed you the output [Model.ListMedicine@250c8ab0, Model.ListMedicine@cb8dd29, Model.ListMedicine@34ced8ae]

Comment: bean.setMedicine_name(obj.getString("medName"));  How would json know getString parameter?   I have suspense the problem is in this line only

Comment: in for loop we are getting JSONObject per array index , then we use that JSONObject to get data from it

Comment: JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);   At this line it is giving error org.json.JSONException: Value at 0 is null.

Comment: dude in your code you are getting ArrayList<ListMedicine> then why you need to parse it again. I am not getting your point. Post your code for activity too. Have you ever done JSON parsing before?

Comment: No I haven't done parsing in the past. I have updated the code.

Comment: if you are getting  data from database and saving it to ArrayList then no need to parse data again. When you are setting adapter in you activity just then pass you that ArrayList which you have fetched from database. Thats it

Answer (score 4):

For me I am using Gson:

```
YourModel obj = gson.fromJson(yourStringJson, YourModel.class);
```

You can read more about Gson here:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Answer (score 3):

Probably, you could use Gson, Jackson, Moshi etc... 
They could be parsing a Java model.

*GitHub Links* - [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) , [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) , [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out..

```
try {

         for(int i=0;i<list.size(); i++){        
    ListMedicine bean = new ListMedicine();
    bean.setMedicine_name(list.get(i).getString("medName"));
    .
    .
    .
    // at last add this into your list
    result.add(bean);
         }


    }catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```